# How to create workspace in A1 cored PowerBI service in azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi

Over the months of exploration into PBI, started with successfully creating a workspace using PowerBI pro license and ended with hosting a pbi report embedding into my custom MVC site using apps-own-data model.

First experience is maximum allowed embedded tokens running out.

My company decided to create a dedicated A1 core powerbi embedded service in a azure account. Now I have overcame token running out of count issue but seems cringy that my powerbi embedded service besides paused still my embedded site runs and accesses powerbi reports without any interruption.

Previously have created AD using embed tool provided by microsoft. I can see my AD been created in azure portal too.

How this is possible to view a pbi report where my azure powerbi embedded service been paused.
Am i supposed to use those pbi reports without getting billed?

Microsoft has limited information on documentation to clarify my doubts, but the PBI community site is somewhat helpful still having trouble getting clarification for the same.

Help required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question:

*How this is possible to view a pbi report where my azure powerbi embedded service been paused. Am i supposed to use those pbi reports without getting billed?*

If the A1 Node is paused, then no, you will not be able to see your report or use the service in your front end. It has to be running to deliver the reports in your custom front end. You can still go into the Power BI Service with an assigned Power BI Pro licence and see your report, the workspace that the report has been deployed to, is flagged as 'embedded capacity' that will be shown as a diamond shape next to it.

You allocate the workspace to a capacity by editing the workspace and selecting the 'Advanced' option then 'Dedicated Capacity'
 [image]

The [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/azure-pbie-pause-start) outlines pausing will not deliver content.

> Pausing a capacity may prevent content from being available within
>   Power BI. Make sure to unassign workspaces from your capacity before
>   pausing to prevent interruption.

Pausing is designed to allow you to stop delivering connect for example, out side business hours, I have a few clients that only run their internal and external report during 7am to 7pm, the other 12 hours the service is paused. The A sku billing costs are reduced to 50%.

Hope that helps

Comment: /You can still go into the Power BI Service with an assigned Power BI Pro licence and see your report, the workspace that the report has been deployed to, is flagged as 'embedded capacity' that will be shown as a diamond shape next to it./

I have created a report using a power bi pro licensed account, but couldnt get that diamond shape next to the report. Am i badly missing something. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Have to assign/remove capacity using api to see/remove diamond symbol. Thanks for your input which helped much.

Comment: I have updatde my answer on how to allocate to capacity using the edit workspace function